# Get todays current date automatically in form in laravel 5

Tags: php, date, laravel

I want to display todays date in date_created field when clicked to create page.

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'articles.store'])!!}
        <div class="form-group">
           <label><b>DATE CREATED</b></label>
           {!! Form::text('date_created',null,array('class'=>'form-control date-picker')) !!}
        </div>
        {!! form::submit('Add',[' class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])!!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
{!! Form::text('date_created', 
    old('date_created', 
        Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')),
    ['class'=>'form-control date-picker']) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `value` -

```
{!! Form::text(
    'date_created',
    date('Y-m-d'),
    array('class'=>'form-control date-picker')
) !!}
```

[DOCS](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#text)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple code, as follows:

```
{!! Form::input('date','start_date',date('Y-m-d'),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Instead of doing complex code. Aslo you need to add time zone in `app.php` file.

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
```

*(For India it is **Asia/Kolkata**)*

Answer (score 0):

**Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for time and date purpose in Laravel**

*Carbon is officially supported by Laravel*

Here's how you can print today's date with Carbon.

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'articles.store'])!!}
        <div class="form-group">
           <label><b>DATE CREATED</b></label>
           {!! Form::text('date_created',Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString(),array('class'=>'form-control date-picker')) !!}
        </div>
        {!! form::submit('Add',[' class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])!!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: If i put datatype as date instead of string in migration file as $table->date('date_created'); then inserted value will be null as 0000-00-00. why is this happening?? can you please tell me the reason

Comment: It shouldn't be null. Make sure if the date_created value is correctly passes to the db.

Comment: I am using date-picker,
migration file:
$table->date('start_date');

Controller file:
 $education->create($request->all());

View page:
@foreach($educations as $education)
                    
                    
                    <td>{!! $education->start_date!!}</td>

Comment: laravel uses date in format as
yy-mm-dd

date-picker uses date in format as:
mm-dd-yy

Answer (score 0):

After Laravel 5.5 you can use now() function to get the current date and time.

In blade file, you can write like this to get date.

```
{!! Form::text('date_created', 
    old('date_created', 
        now()->format('Y-m-d')),
    ['class'=>'form-control date-picker']) !!}
```

[image]